Converting circular structure to JSON --> starting at object with constructor 'Object'
I am building a MERN app. I am fetching data from backend and based on that data , i am setting my navigation in my APp.js.
Code for App.js :
import {Navigate, Route , Routes} from 'react-router-dom' 
import Homepage from './components/Homepage'
import Login from './components/Login'
import Register from './components/Register'
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar';
import RightPanel from './components/RightPanel'
import {Toaster} from 'react-hot-toast'

import ProfilePage from './components/ProfilePage'
import NotificationPage from './components/NotificationPage';
import { PROXY_URL } from './utils/constants';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function App() {

  const [user, setUser] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getMe = async ()=>{
      const response = await fetch(`${PROXY_URL}/api/auth/me`);
      const answer = await response.json();

      console.log(answer);

      if (response.ok) {
        setUser(true);
      }
      else{
        setUser(false);
      }
      
    }
    getMe();
  })
  

    // if (isLoading) {
    //  return (
    //      <div className='h-screen flex justify-center items-center'>
    //          <LoadingSpinner size='lg' />
    //      </div>
    //  );
    // }

  return (
    <div className="App flex max-w-6xl mx-auto overflow-x-hidden">
      <Sidebar/>
     <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={user ? <Homepage/> : <Navigate to={<Login/>}/>}/>
      <Route path='/login' element={<Login/>}/>
      <Route path='/signup' element={<Register/>}/>
      <Route path='/notifications' element={<NotificationPage/>}/>
      <Route path='/profile/:username' element={<ProfilePage/>}/>
     </Routes>
     <RightPanel/>
     <Toaster/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

When i run this using create react app, I get the following error :

I also used react query , but even when i disabled it , it gives the same error.
What to do ?

The re are few potential issues in your code that need to be addressed first.
For example, the first issue is in the following route:
<Route path='/' element={user ? <Homepage/> : <Navigate to={<Login/>}/>}/>

In above route, the 'to' prop in Navigate should be a string not a Component, if you want to render component then you can to it like this:
<Route path='/' element={user ? <Homepage/> : <Login/>}/> 

or you can solve it like this also:
<Route path='/' element={user ? <Homepage/> : <Navigate to='/login'/>}/>

There other issue is that you are not Handling the error properly which maybe a cause of errors. You can do it properly like this:
useEffect(() => {
const getMe = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${PROXY_URL}/api/auth/me`);
    const answer = await response.json();
    console.log(answer);
    
    if (response.ok) {
      setUser(true);
    } else {
      setUser(false);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching user data:', error);
    setUser(false);
  } finally {
    setIsLoading(false);
  }
};
getMe();

}, []);
Finally, Implement a loading state to handle the period during which the user data is being fetched.

Hey thanks ! that worked
